# Export blender scene to USDZ

Tags: materials, export

I made a bubble materials in blender and applied it to my model. Now my client wants me to export the scene to usdz file to be viewed in apple devices so I did, but when I view the file, it only has solid color instead of realistic bubbles. Also the file only comes with principled bsdf it doesn't include all the nodes that I used. I'm pretty sure that my export settings is correct and also tried to play with it but the results were still the same. Is there something that I need to do first before exporting the file? Or is there any way to do it? I am not familiar with usdz file format and it gives me headache.